# Where does CS:GO host the game?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

just want to ask, on CS:GO - if I create a lobby and invite a whole lot of friends, does it host the server on STEAM or does every friend connect into my instance?

I'm assuming it hosts on STEAM otherwise there would be major lag issues, but we've been having major lag issues so I'm just double checking.

Comment: In my knowledge, Steam hosts game _installers_, and information server / API for "friends" to get in touch and other games to know which friend is connected. It doesn't host the actual various _game servers_. The games are always hosted either on dedicated servers from the game company, dedicated servers by other players, or directly locally on players's machines. Your question is therefore more like : Are game hosted locally or on external servers?

Comment: You can tell whether you're the host or not by checking your ping. The host always has 0 ping.